# Keeping certain variables after model validation rules fail in cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, validation, variables, controller, cakephp-2.0

So I'm using jquery tabs for a page with a form, and we're using certain php variables like `$image` (with data such as dimensions and path) in `if isset` conditions inside the view to "unlock" further tabs as the user completes actions (such as uploading an image at this example). At some point I have to use some validation rules, and the problem is if the user makes an error and validation rules fail, the page is reloaded with the variables `$image` etc gone, so the user basically has to start the form from the beginning (locked tabs and all).

At the moment I'm using something like this:

```
if ($this->Report->save($this->data)) { //validation rules run here
    //do stuff
else{
    $this->set("err", 1);
```

so I can at least have some of the tabs unlocked on page reload using the `$err` variable, but I also need to maintain specific variables with actual data like `$image` that I mentioned before (to show a preview), which I cannot figure out a way to do.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store your data in the session and delete them when appropriate

Comment: Its a start I guess, I'll use that.